# Objective-C callback block for BASS FX

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, bass

I'm trying to use the audio library BASS in my application. I'm trying to use a method which triggers a callback when it detects a beat in the music.

This is my current code:

```
void* (^myBlock)(DWORD, double, void *) = ^(DWORD handle, double time, void *user) {
    return nil;
};

BASS_FX_BPM_BeatDecodeGet(bpmStream, 0.0, playBackDuration, BASS_FX_BPM_BKGRND, myBlock,NULL);
```

The callback is defined in the header file as:

```
typedef void (CALLBACK BPMBEATPROC)(DWORD chan, double beatpos, void *user);
```

The error message is:

```
Passing 'void *(^)(DWORD, double, void *)' to parameter of incompatible type 'BPMBEATPROC *' (aka 'void (*)(DWORD, double, void *)')
```

I'm pretty sure the block only needs a small modification, but I'm not familiar with Objective-C.

Comment: your block is returning a `void*` when the typedef is expecting just `void`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Razib He is asking why he can't pass his block as a callback.

Comment: @Razib Yes, sorry. I would like to know how to change the block so it will work.

I changed void* to void. This is the new error message: Passing 'void (^)(DWORD, double, void *)' to parameter of incompatible type 'BPMBEATPROC *' (aka 'void (*)(DWORD, double, void *)')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a block that returns a `void*` to a parameter that expects a function pointer that returns nothing (`void`).

You need to declare your block as a function returning `void` and pass it as the callback:

```
void myFunction(DWORD handle, double time, void *user) {
    //function code here
}
```

And then pass it to the library just like the block:

```
BASS_FX_BPM_BeatDecodeGet(bpmStream, 0.0, playBackDuration, BASS_FX_BPM_BKGRND, myFunction,NULL);
```

For more information about function pointers, see [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work).